# INVALID UNUSED ETKT REQ

Tags: api, sabre

Finally worked out my credentials and got my TJR updated to call the UnusedeTicketReportRQ, but I am unable to get past the error it is throwing. Weirdly it is status 200, so im guessing it doesn't like my formatting?

```
=> Request
 POST /websvc
 <soap11:Envelope 
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:stlh="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v120" xmlns:sws="http://webservices.sabre.com" xmlns:sws_xsd="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:tns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap11:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">example.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>####</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>new-id</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">UnusedeTicketReportLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>UnusedeTicketReportLLSRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>3af13f81-9b59-488b-abab-997aae420118</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-05-13T05:54:02.578Z</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CER
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap11:Header>
    <soap11:Body>
        <sws_xsd:UnusedeTicketReportRQ Version="2.0.0">
            <sws_xsd:eTicketReport StartDate="04-22"/>
        </sws_xsd:UnusedeTicketReportRQ>
    </soap11:Body>
</soap11:Envelope>
```

and my response looks like:

```
<= Response
 Status(200)
 <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader 
        soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">example.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>####</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>new-id</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">UnusedeTicketReportLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>UnusedeTicketReportLLSRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1268174212410700151</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-05-13T05:54:01</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>3af13f81-9b59-488b-abab-997aae420118</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
</eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" valueType="String">
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICE
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <UnusedeTicketReportRS 
        Version="2.0.0" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error timeStamp="2017-05-13T00:54:01-05:00" type="BusinessLogic">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>INVALID UNUSED ETKT REQ </stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
</UnusedeTicketReportRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how you got that error, the error I get is: NO UNUSED ITEMS AVAILABLE TO DISPLAY-1653

Comment: @Wisdoom I believe you get that because you are using Sabre Red or some hosted terminal, correct? I see that error in Sabre Red as well, but the webservices API returns that extremely unuseful error message.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I was checking SRW since the errors are usually the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, turns out Sabre doesn't clarify the errors very well. All this means is that there was nothing returned. Should probably say that vs invalid request.